# XSL 1.0 distinct values from a template

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

is anyone able to help me with this?

this is my XML -

```
<grandparent>
  <parent>
    <child>apple</child>
  </parent>
  <parent>
    <child>apple</child>
    <child>orange</child>
    <child>apple</child>
    <child>apple</child>
    <child>apple</child>
  </parent>
  <parent>
    <child>pear</child>
    <child>apple</child>
    <child>pear</child>
    <child>pear</child>
  </parent>
</granparent>
```

I have a template which I pass parent into and it spits out all the child tags, but I'm wanting it to only spit out the unique child values.

I've had a search around and everyone's suggestion of using a key doesn't seem to work because it seems to only get the unique values in the scope of the grandparent, not the scope of the parent.

This is what I have -

```
<xsl:template name="uniqueChildren">
  <xsl:param name="parent" />

  <xsl:for-each select="$parent/child">
    <xsl:value-of select="." />
  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

currently shows -

```
apple
apple orange apple apple apple
pear apple pear pear
```

My code when I tried a key -

```
<xsl:key name="children" match="child" use="." />

<xsl:template name="uniqueChildren">
  <xsl:param name="parent" />

  <xsl:for-each select="$parent/child[generate-id() = generate-id(key('children', .)[1])]">
    <xsl:value-of select="." />
  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

when I tried using a key it showed -

```
apple
orange
pear
```

what I want it to show -

```
apple
apple orange
pear apple
```

Comment: "when I tried using a key" - can you show the XSLT you used in this case?  It will probably just be a case of adjusting the key definition slightly to take account of the parent element.

Comment: I've included the key example above, thanks.

Comment: Looked further into it and a key is a top level element, so creating the key inside the template doesn't work either, seems to break the entire page...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're very close with the key approach, the trick is that you need to include the identity of the parent node as part of the grouping key:

```
<xsl:key name="children" match="child" use="concat(generate-id(..), '|', .)" />

<xsl:template name="uniqueChildren">
  <xsl:param name="parent" />

  <xsl:for-each select="$parent/child[generate-id() = generate-id(
           key('children', concat(generate-id($parent), '|', .))[1])]">
    <xsl:value-of select="." />
  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

This creates key values of the form "`<id-of-parent>|apple`", "`<id-of-parent>|orange`", etc.

---

Edit: in your comment you say "In my actual data, the child nodes aren't a direct child of the parent nodes. There's 2 levels between parent and child, e.g. parent/././child"

In this case the same principle works, you just need to adjust the key a bit.  The point is that the key value needs to include the `generate-id` of the node that defines the scope of the uniqueness check.  So if you know you've always got exactly two levels in between (`parent/x/y/child`) then you'd use

```
<xsl:key name="children" match="child"
   use="concat(generate-id(../../..), '|', .)" />
```

or if the `child` elements might be at different levels within the `parent` then you could use something like

```
<xsl:key name="children" match="child"
   use="concat(generate-id(ancestor::parent[1]), '|', .)" />
```

(`ancestor::parent[1]` is the nearest ancestor of the target element whose name is `parent`)

Comment: Thanks for your response Ian, but using the above code is returning blanks

Comment: In my actual data, the child nodes aren't a direct child of the parent nodes. There's 2 levels between parent and child, e.g. parent/././child can that make a difference?

Comment: I have obviously ammended the first part of the select in the for-each to reflect that

Comment: The above was what was causing issues, found my answer here - concat(generate-id(../../..), '|' etc.

Comment: @DerekHo if you want to pick out distinct values within a grandparent then the principle is the same, you just need to tweak the key to include the `generate-id` of the correct scoping node.

Comment: Thanks very much ian, you're a star! :D